# MediaElement UWP Windows 1709 crashing

Tags: c#, uwp

I have had a project for a while, that worked fine. I didn't touch it for about a month and I believe in that time the new version (Fall build 1709) of Windows landed. Currently, neither my project, nor the sample project (which I downloaded as a sanity check that there's nothing wrong with my code) for Windows MediaElement work for me. Here is the code being called:

```
        StorageFile file = await openMediaFile.PickSingleFileAsync();
        demoMedia.AutoPlay = true;
        IRandomAccessStream stream = await file.OpenAsync(FileAccessMode.Read);
        demoMedia.SetSource(stream, "");
        demoMedia.Play();
```

The code crashes on `demoMedia.SetSource(stream, "");` with an error `System.IO.FileNotFoundException: 'The specified module could not be found. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x8007007E)'`. Does anyone know what could be the cause and how to fix it? I tried using `demoMedia.SetPlaybackSource(MediaSource.CreateFromStorageFile(file));` (I used setsource before and it worked fine), but that results in: `System.TypeLoadException: 'Requested Windows Runtime type 'Windows.Media.Core.MediaSource' is not registered.'` . I assume something broke/ was changed with the update and now the module is either named somehow else, or is missing?

Comment: How about if you create a blank UWP app, and to see if it is work with the above simple code snippet? What's your project target version? What's the "sample project " you are using for testing?  For the common exception, have you check [this thread](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/f609f52e-00f6-4ada-9d6e-7129b85d3d4d/the-specified-module-could-not-be-found-exception-from-hresult-0x8007007e?forum=netfx64bit)?

Comment: I suspect a problem with the installed SDK or the version of Visual Studio you are using. Are sure you have updated everything to the latest versions?

Comment: I seem to have sorted it out. The newest fall build apparently removed the Windows Media player which was installed as an extra. I was running Windows N version, which is the standard one in Europe and comes without some features (like Media Player). Since this class relies on the Windows Media Player for showing, it crashed since it did not find it. I remember installing the Media Player a few years back, but have forgotten since then and I didn't expect an update to remove it.